# How can I flash an embedded device with new linux software?

Tags: embedded, camera, mips, flash

I have this IP camera that I bought that's really pretty shady (it streams all the videos to some S3 bucket and forces me to use their software), but I'm pretty sure it runs embedded linux and I'm hoping I can just reinstall a fresh build. I'm a heavy linux user but I'm totally new to this level of modding.

To start, the camera has a `Ingenic T31` chip, which appears to be a MIPS processor. You can see from this photo there is some other chip below it, but it doesn't have any labels or anything. It's right next to the wireless antenna so make that's the radio controller?

Second, in the attached board, there are 4 holes that look like they might be fit for a USB adaptor. I have seen people solder ports into those, but I'm not sure if there is a way to connect without solder. (I'm terrible with solder).

Finally, there is also a micro SD card slot on the reverse side of that second board.

Aside from figuring out HOW to flash it, I also need to find the correct build of linux to install and run the camera. I'm planning to use this with HomeAssistant.

I know there is probably a lot of info out there I can find on my own, but maybe I'm not searching for the right buzzwords. I'd be happy just to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: *"Ingenic T31 chip, which appears to be a MIPS processor"… Oh wait ! A MIPS core that can certainly run Linux AND a RISC-V core running some undefined RTOS. Well… because of that RTOS… I would not venture myself in a project of flashing whatever…

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Forget it.

Long answer:

If you have a well-documented system, you can learn how to build your own emedded linux with Yocto, flash it on the system and we can assist on prolems that might appear (and they will appear with such an exotic system!).

But here, you'd have to reverse engineer a closed system. You don't know how to debug the system, don't know how to set the boot order to make it boot from MicroSD card, don't know what ports are connected to what devices to write a matching device tree.

The shortest way to reach your goal is to throw that thing away and start from the scratch designing your own hardware and build your own Yocto.